Can I call Windows Explorer context menu using python?
I'm working on my diploma work and i need to implement windows explorer context menu on right click in my treeView QFileSystemModel (I'm using PyQT6, PySide6). I know it would be much easier to do if i were using C++, but its too late for me to change programming language.
So basically, i have my list of files and when i right click, windows explorer context menu should show up (example of this can be seen in treeSize and everything apps)
I tried to use win32api and ctypes but lack required knowledge to actually achieve something. Also ChatGPT didnt help much and there is no particular documentation on the internet (or i didn`t find it).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Research more, implement a prototype and ask a specific question. Anyway, see this question.
